# Map points from one camera to another

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration

I have two camera's lets say A and B. Camera B is mounted slightly above (say 20 cm for example) camera A and has a slightly different angle then camera A.

Now I want too take a picture with both camera's and draw a point at exact the same location on both images. I need to somehow calibrate the images so when I draw a point at lets say (100, 100) on the image from camera A I end op at the same location on camera B.

For this to work I need to detect (find) the deviation from lets say camera A to camera B. With this deviation I can then translate points from camera A to camera B. I have done some research and found something called [Stereo Reflection](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) but this seems not of any use because it tries to find x, y, z, positions of points in 3D space. I only need to translate 2D coordinates from one image to another.

I am a beginner with openCv but I know this must be possible using openCv but I don't know where to start. Can any one point me to the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried Teo Bendit's answer on How to Transform Points from A Plane to A Different Plane at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2944635/356222?

Comment: If you want to use the OpenCV, is this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43565754/5595995 a guide?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are looking for image registration.